# add 1 to c++ bitset

Tags: c++, boost, bitset

I have a c++ bitset of given length. I want to generate all possible combinations of this bitset for which I thought of adding 1 2^bitset.length times. How to do this? Boost library solution is also acceptable

Comment: well... I couldn't see an add operation and manually checking all bits doesn't seem feasible. So I haven't tried anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All possible combinations? Just use 64-bit unsigned integer and make your life easier.

Comment: Then i will have to convert that integer to bitset again and again to retrieve values of individual bits. Since bitset< some variable size > is not possible in STL bitset, I will use boost. And if I make bitset< value > mybitset, and value = 2, I will require 00010 instead of 10. Is that possible? Hope it makes sense to you :)

Comment: No, you won't have to convert it back to bitset to retrieve individual bits -- learn how to use bitwise operators. 00010 is the same as 10; it's only up to you how many leading zeros of an integer you want to extract.

Comment: you mean I can see if if third bit of an int is set or not? Please point me somewhere!

Comment: @wirate: Learn the magic of the `&`, `<<` and `>>` operators when applied to integers.

Comment: `bool isNthBitSet(unsigned long long bitset, unsigned char bitNum) {
return bitset & (1ULL << bitNum);
}` Of course I ignored overflow problems.

Comment: @wirate I *have* pointed you somewhere: search for bitwise operators. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation or http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
/*
 * This function adds 1 to the bitset.
 *
 * Since the bitset does not natively support addition we do it manually. 
 * If XOR a bit with 1 leaves it as one then we did not overflow so we can break out
 * otherwise the bit is zero meaning it was previously one which means we have a bit 
 * overflow which must be added 1 to the next bit etc.
 */
void increment(boost::dynamic_bitset<>& bitset)
{
    for(int loop = 0;loop < bitset.count(); ++loop)
    {
        if ((bitset[loop] ^= 0x1) == 0x1)
        {    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not best, but brute force way, but you can add 1 by converting using `to_ulong()`

```cpp
bitset<32> b (13);
b = b.to_ulong() + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using boost library, you can try the following:

For example, a bitset of length 4

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitset;
for (int i = 0; i < pow(2.0, 4); i++) {
    bitset = boost::dynamic_bitset<>(4, i);

    std::cout << bitset << std::endl;

}
```